# Sending a firestore timestamp to external API UTC loss

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a timestamp stored in Firestore like 18/2/1995 00:00:00 as a DoB storing it BST (+1 UTC)

I am trying to pull that date out in a function, and call an API with that value as part of the body.

No matter how I try and to date it, I lose that hour.

I have tried

1. the toDate() from firebase
2. let date = new Date(newValue.dob.seconds * 1000);
3. sending the ISO string
4. .toUTCString() (c# does not like)
5. DateTime on the c# side
6. DateTimeOffset on the side.

I am not sure which side is wrong at the moment.

on the c# API side, I have used DateTimes and DateTimeOffsets and with the former, I get the date minus an hour, and with the latter I get the date missing an hour with +0:00 on the end.

How is this meant to be set up. I was hopinh a DateTimeOffset object would just pick up any UTC info a date in JS has?

Code I am trying

```
  let date = newValue.dob.toDate();
  console.log(date);
  console.log(date.getMinutes());
  console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset());
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());

  console.log(date);
```

and

```
  let date = new Date(newValue.dob.seconds * 1000);
  console.log(date);
  console.log(date.getMinutes());
  console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset());
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());

  console.log(date);
```

both times I get no offset value, here is the datafield in firestore [image: DataField in firestore]

output is always

[image: output]

Comment: Your question should show actual code that isn't working the way you expect.  Anyone should be able to copy that code and run it to verify the result that you observe.  Without that, we can't see what you might be doing wrong.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

When you render the timestamp, it will add any localized timezone offsets available to it from the OS as timestamps themselves are UTC-based.

If you want to regionalize the timestamp to your region, you must find the offset from a new Date object: `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` and then add it to the minutes.

Comment: thanks, that would work if I got any offset value. 
I feel like the information firestore gives me about the data is just not enough

Comment: I know how you feel, me and a few colleagues are hoping to fix that in the coming months. that being said, it is implied as the timestamps are UTC rather than GMT